# Python syntax for namedtuple inside a namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

Is it possible to have a `namedtuple` inside another `namedtuple`?

For example:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Position = namedtuple('Position', 'x y')
Token = namedtuple('Token', ['key', 'value', Position])
```

which gives a *"ValueError: Type names and field names must be valid identifiers"*

Also, I am curious if there is a more *Pythonic approach* to build such a nested container?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are mixing up two concepts - structure of `namedtuple`, and values assigned to them. Structure requires list of unique names. Values may be anything, including another `namedtuple`.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Position = namedtuple('Position', 'x y')
Token = namedtuple('Token', ['key', 'value', 'position'])

t = Token('ABC', 'DEF', Position(1, 2))
assert t.position.x == 1
```

Comment: Silly me! Thanks for the explanation and the accompanied code. So, is that nested namedtuple considered a good practice? Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: It's perfectly fine data structure with another data structure nested inside it. If it's correct for problem you're solving, why not? You just have to keep in mind that it's a data structure, not a class. For complex objects you're usually better with creating a class with appropriate methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here a general function to transform a nested dictionary to a nested namedtuple

```py
from collections import namedtuple

def dict2namedtuple(name, d):
    values, keys = [], []
    for k in d:
        keys.append(k)

        v = d[k]
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            values.append(dict2namedtuple(k, v))
        else:
            values.append(v)

    T = namedtuple(name, keys)
    return T(*values)


def namedtuple2dict(nt):
    d = {}
    for k in nt._fields:
        v = getattr(nt, k)
        try:
            d[k] = namedtuple2dict(v)
        except AttributeError:
            d[k] = v
    return d


test_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 3, 'e': 4}}
nt = dict2namedtuple('test', d=test_dict)
dc = namedtuple2dict(nt)
assert dc == test_dict
print('namedtuple', nt)
print('dict', dc)
```

EDIT:
I added a function for the inverse problem `namedtuple2dict`. In my experience `namedtuple._asidct()` works fine, but @Chev_603 mentioned some problems.

Comment: I'd like to see how it is done in reverse, ie nested namedtuples to dictionaries

Comment: there exists already a function: `nnt._asdict()`

Comment: Yes, but it does not work recursively in every case.

Comment: I added the inverse function, let me know if this does not work in your cases.